# ActiveRecord count after select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a pagination helper like this:

```
  def paginate(collection)
    count = collection.count
    collection.offset(@offset).limit(@per_page)
  end
```

for `collection` I only want to select certain fields, but the behavior of `count` changes if I do a select. Is there a way that I can pass in e.g. `Model.all.select(:foo, :bar)` as `collection` here?

Comment: Does `Model.pluck(:foo, :bar)` is what you looking for?

Comment: @Pavan: no, `pluck `is eager

Comment: How the `collection` look like currently?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are after, but try `.size` instead of `.count`. `.count` is doing a db question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its true that ActiveRecord [`count`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count) will, without arguments, query the `COUNT` based on the attributes specified with `select`:

```
Model.select(:attribute).count
   (1987.0ms)  SELECT COUNT("models"."attribute") FROM "models"
```

However you can override this by passing a SQL or attribute argument to `count`:

```
Model.select(:attribute).count("*")
   (8.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "models"
Model.select(:attribute).count(:id)
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT("models"."id") FROM "models"
Model.select(:attribute).count("DISTINCT id")
   (3.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM "models"
```

Note that the first of these generates the same SQL as `count` without arguments on a scope without a `select`:

```
Model.count
   (1.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "models"
```